# text file - rows to colums using altova mapforce

Tags: altova

How can I convert a comma separated text file into a line separated text file using only Altova MapForce.
Is there a way I can put an 'enter' into the MapForce concat function?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the Input as Text File there right click the input component and see the property. By default there is Comma for separation of values. Change the value. Other wise one more option is split the input text file.
[[1] Here is link](http://www.altova.com/mapforce/convert-text.html)
[[2] Book](https://manual.altova.com/Mapforce/mapforceenterprise/flextutorial.htm)

Very important think for you there is nothing ready to eat in altova Mapforce.